# MASM32 String Input

Tags: assembly, masm32

I'm trying to get into assembly, and thought that MASM32 would be a good start. But I'm encountering an issue. I'm reading a lot of Iczelion's online tutorials and would like to know how to display a string (thru keyboard input) instead of just a single key input.

This was the code he provided:

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none
WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib

.data 
ClassName db "SimpleWinClass",0 
AppName  db "Our First Window",0 
char WPARAM 20h                         ; the character the program receives from keyboard

.data? 
hInstance HINSTANCE ? 
CommandLine LPSTR ?

.code 
start: 
    invoke GetModuleHandle, NULL 
    mov    hInstance,eax 
    invoke GetCommandLine
    mov CommandLine,eax
    invoke WinMain, hInstance,NULL,CommandLine, SW_SHOWDEFAULT 
    invoke ExitProcess,eax

WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE,hPrevInst:HINSTANCE,CmdLine:LPSTR,CmdShow:DWORD 
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX 
    LOCAL msg:MSG 
    LOCAL hwnd:HWND 
    mov   wc.cbSize,SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX 
    mov   wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW 
    mov   wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc 
    mov   wc.cbClsExtra,NULL 
    mov   wc.cbWndExtra,NULL 
    push  hInst 
    pop   wc.hInstance 
    mov   wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_WINDOW+1 
    mov   wc.lpszMenuName,NULL 
    mov   wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET ClassName 
    invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION 
    mov   wc.hIcon,eax 
    mov   wc.hIconSm,eax 
    invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW 
    mov   wc.hCursor,eax 
    invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc 
    invoke CreateWindowEx,NULL,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\ 
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,\ 
           CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL,NULL,\ 
           hInst,NULL 
    mov   hwnd,eax 
    invoke ShowWindow, hwnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL 
    invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd 
    .WHILE TRUE 
                invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg,NULL,0,0 
                .BREAK .IF (!eax) 
                invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg 
                invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg 
        .ENDW 
    mov     eax,msg.wParam 
    ret 
WinMain endp

WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM 
    LOCAL hdc:HDC 
    LOCAL ps:PAINTSTRUCT

    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY 
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL 
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CHAR 
        push wParam 
        pop  char 
        invoke InvalidateRect, hWnd,NULL,TRUE 
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_PAINT 
        invoke BeginPaint,hWnd, ADDR ps 
        mov    hdc,eax 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,0,0,ADDR char,1 
        invoke EndPaint,hWnd, ADDR ps 
    .ELSE 
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam 
        ret 
    .ENDIF 
    xor    eax,eax 
    ret 
WndProc endp 
end start
```

Comment: Since you seem to be creating a windowed application (rather than a console application) it would make more sense to add an Edittext control to your window that can recieve user input.

Comment: I see. But how do I add that? Sorry for the question. I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing GUI programming in MASM it seems. Since you just want to display a string in a simple way, try this.

Here is for a console application

```
.686P
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096

EXTERN  _printf     :PROC
EXTERN  _scanf      :PROC

.DATA
szRead          BYTE    "%s", 0
szStr           BYTE    80 DUP (?)

.CODE

_main   PROC

    lea     edx, szStr
    push    edx
    lea     ebx, szRead
    push    ebx
    call    _scanf
    add     esp, 8

    push    edx
    lea     ebx, szRead
    push    ebx
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 8

    xor     eax, eax
    ret

_main   ENDP

END
```

To compile the console version: ml.exe hello.asm /link libcmt.lib kernel32.lib

Comment: Thanks! But what if I wanted the string input to be displayed in a windows program instead of console?